# reuse script or publish a private google sheets script add-on without gsuite or being a business

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-addon

I'd like to reuse a Google Apps Script between multiple sheets on my personal Google account without publishing the script publicaly. One approach that I'm trying to avoid is to simply copy and paste the script between each sheet that I'm using.

After some reading my impression is that this is typically done by publishing an add-on. I am also under the impression that this can (or could) be done privately, so that no code review is needed and you don't need to pay anything. Most of the related questions I've found on SO seem to have out of date answers (chrome web store instead of GSuite Marketplace) or are too simple (share by publishing an add-on) or refer to gsuite users/admin, etc.

Assuming I need to publish an add-on to get easy sharing across all of my sheets I'm told I need to convert my project to a Google Cloud Project. So I created a Google Cloud Project and then went to transfer my code to that project by going to "Resources - Cloud Platform project" and entering my project number. However, when I do that it tells me that I need to enable oauth for the project and it takes me to a page which looks like it will require formal code review.

I am under the impression that private publishing may be possible if I am an organization. So I went back to the Google Cloud Console and tried to create an organization. Here however, it seems like either I need to be subscribing to GSuite or I need to enable Cloud Identity. The latter seems only pertinent to businesses as during the sign up it asks me for my business name and business domain (e.g. jims-business.com); I stopped when it asked me for my domain.

So again, my question is, is it possible to share a Google script between multiple sheets on my personal account without making a public add-on? After way to much time reading through Google terminology my impression is no, but I'd be happy to be proven wrong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to be a G Suite user to publish an add-on, but you do if you want to do it as "internal only", as it requires a valid domain.

I'm afraid you will have to copy the same Script for each file and use an [onOpen function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#getting_started).

Comment: It seems like this may have not always been the case? I'm curious if anyone has created a clever workaround. I'll leave this open for another day and then accept if no one else responds. Thanks.